# List all available apps from Qlikview and Qliksense?

Tags: javascript, qlikview, qliksense

Our organization is using both qliksense and qlikview, and as such, getting to all of the available apps (hopefully this terminology is right - I'm new to this - each report, which I think is called an app) that a user might have access to is challenging (having to go to multiple sites).

I'm looking to create a simple web page that lists out all available apps from both qlikview and qliksense (which are each on separate servers). Is this possible just using javascript, and if so, how might I go about that? Just a point in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2):

This question isn't the greatest.  But if I HAD to solve that problem, I would have 3 components.

-The first would be some kind of Powershell task that would monitor the QlikView applications folder for changes.  It would read the names of all the Qlikview apps and then it would write them out to a share

-The second part would be an API service call to my QlikSense install. Using something like this https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/3.1/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/CreatingAppLoadingData/CreateApps/list-apps.htm

-The third part would be a webserver that would cobble together all the information from those two sources and present them to a user.

This task isn't hard if you are familiar with the components, but if you don't you might have some problems.